# Creating a function in SQL Azure master database

Tags: azure-sql-database

Is there anyway to create a user defined function in SQL Azure master database?

How to get control over SQL Azure master database including write permissons?

Thanks
Jags

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot get control of the master database -- the master database is read-only and used to maintain logins/security info (and I think other meta data that's auto-managed).  See this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-provision-sql-server/)